"Circular definition of repositories" in Bazel
I am using StableHLO via the Bazel WORKSPACE
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

STABLEHLO_COMMIT = "8c7d87b6f4d3e1d692afb94494530ed993b6eb59"

http_archive(
    name = "stablehlo",
    build_file = "@stablehlo//:BUILD.bazel",
    url = "https://github.com/openxla/stablehlo/archive/{commit}.tar.gz".format(commit = STABLEHLO_COMMIT),
)

That works fine. But when I depend on this in a BUILD file
cc_library(
    name = "reference",
    linkstatic = True,
    alwayslink = True,
    srcs = glob(["*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    deps = [
        "@stablehlo//:reference_ops",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

located at src/stablehlo/stablehlo/reference/ in my project, I see
ERROR: Circular definition of repositories:
.-> @@stablehlo [self-edge]
`--
INFO: Repository stablehlo instantiated at:
  /ir/WORKSPACE:5:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/28c542a9beec5e078b3e48145a4e82ef/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:382:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:ir' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.118s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: 
    Fetching repository @@stablehlo; starting

I can't see any circular reference here. I have tried changing the name of reference to foo in the BUILD (adjusting other files accordingly), but with no luck. I have another setup like this that uses local_repository and that works fine.
Note my root BUILD file is
cc_binary(
    name = "ir",
    linkshared = True,
    linkstatic = True,
    srcs = [
        "//src/stablehlo/stablehlo/reference",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//src/stablehlo/stablehlo/reference",
    ],
)

I am using Bazel 6.1.2 with
build --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++17"
build --nobuild_runfile_links
build --nolegacy_external_runfiles
build --experimental_repo_remote_exec


This line is the problem: build_file = "@stablehlo//:BUILD.bazel",
To define A you depend on something in A which requires A first.
In the case BUILD.bazel is already part of the archive it does not make to reference it - you can use http_archive without referencing a build file. In this case, Bazel will use the BUILD file that comes with the archive.
Consider also switching to Bazel modules and archive_override which works very similar.

Thanks, but why does it not complain if I include that but omit the dependency in the nested BUILD, "@stablehlo//:reference_ops"?
